# Auto-incrementing ClickOnce version using MSBuild and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I've seen variants of this problem on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but I've not seen a real solution for my case. So here goes...

I have a C# project (not ASP.NET - WinForms) that I am currently publishing as a ClickOnce deployment within Visual Studio 2012. I am copying the results to a shared network drive for distribution. I am using Git/BitBucket for source control and I have a Jenkins installation available to me. What I want to do is automate the process such that I check in my code, then set off a build in Jenkins that gets the new code, Builds and publishes it, incrementing the revision number, then copying the results to the shared drive. I know how to do all of those steps except for incrementing the revision number - MSBuild's /Publish action does not do that.

How can I get that effect? Either an internal auto-incremented revision number or assignment of the Jenkins build number would work for me. Thanks.

Comment: just to clarify, you need to _increment_ the revision number in your source control right?

Comment: That would be nice, but not completely necessary - as long as the finished release displays the proper revision number. If I'm doing an auto-increment, I would assume that that number would have to be checked back in to source control, but if I'm using the Jenkins build number, that probably doesn't have to happen. Make sense?